# Share macros across GTM containers

Tags: synchronization, google-tag-manager

Is it possible to have a single location for macros that several different containers (for different websites) use?  This should facilitate keeping them up to date and also prevent errors from copy-paste or re-coding from scratch.  Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

The best GTM-only solution I've found is to firstly develop all the common M/R/T *(Macros/Rules/Tags)* in one container then export that to a JSON file that is imported as the basis of the actual containers.  This leaves the issue of having to update any new common M/R/T on each individual container.
[Google's Support page](https://support.google.com/tagmanager/answer/6106997?hl=en).

I've also found a [GreaseMonkey/TamperMonkey script](https://github.com/maschek/gtm_import_export) for Firefox/Chrome that facilitates the process, but it still requires a similar workflow.